# Spring Security URL based authorization

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to implement URL based authorization in one of the my spring mvc project. In my spring mvc project,I am using java configuration.I have refer this site https://www.baeldung.com/role-and-privilege-for-spring-security-registration to implement Role and Privilege based authorization.

So i created following tables for  implementation.

This is user table.

[image]

This role table.

[image]

This is mapping table between role and privilege.

[image]

This is privilege table.

[image]

Following is code from Controller side.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value={"/user"})
public class UserController {

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value={"/userDashboard"},method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String userDashboard(ModelMap model){
        return "UserDashboard";
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value={"/testUser"},method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String testUser(ModelMap model){
        return "TestUser";
    }

}
```

Following is code to implement UserDetailService.

```
@Service("authService")
@Transactional
public class AuthService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDaoInterface userDaoInterface;

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(AuthService.class);

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) {
        User user = null;
        try {
            user = userDaoInterface.getUserByUserName(userName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("AuthService @loadUserByUsername --Exception while fetching user from username",e);
        }

        if(user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found");
        }

        UserDetails userDetails = new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(),
                user.getPassword(),!user.getIsDeleted(),true,true,true,getAuthorities(user.getRole()));

        log.info("UserService userDetails " + userDetails);

        return userDetails;
    }

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(Role role) {  
        return getGrantedAuthorities(getPrivileges(role));
    }

    private List<String> getPrivileges(Role role) {
        List<String> privileges = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Privilege> collection = new ArrayList<>();
        collection.addAll(role.getPrivileges());
        for (Privilege item : collection) {
            privileges.add(item.getName());
        }
        return privileges;
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(List<String> privileges) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String privilege : privileges) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(privilege));
        }
        return authorities;
    }
}
```

Spring Security Configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
@ComponentScan("com.project")
public class AppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService authService;

    @Autowired
    PersistentTokenRepository tokenRepository;

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(authService);
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
      return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(authService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices getPersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices() {
        return new PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices("remember-me", authService, tokenRepository);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
         .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/login")
        .and()
        .logout().logoutUrl("/logout")
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
        .and().csrf()
        .and().rememberMe().rememberMeParameter("remember-me").tokenRepository(tokenRepository).tokenValiditySeconds(86400);
    }
}
```

When i logged into system by credential which is stored in user table and try to access url like http://localhost:8080/RestProject/user/testUser then user is authorized to access this url but As per above implementation user should not be allow to access this url. So I am not able to understand how dynamic permission will work here?

Comment: Where is your Spring Security configuation? It is not enough to expose a `UserDetailsService`.

Comment: This should be configured in Spring Security Configuration.

Comment: @Supun Dharmarathne If it should be in spring security configuration then what is meaning of above implementation inside getAuthorities method  which is in UserDetailService.

Comment: @Supun Dharmarathne I got your point that why we need to require some configuration in spring security configuration. So i need to add code like .antMatchers("/user/userDashboard").hasRole("Admin") in spring security configuration.

Is there any way to register only permission of login user instead of register permission of all roles by using antMatchers?

Comment: @HimanshuPatel You configured that all logged in users can access `http://localhost:8080/RestProject/user/testUser`. Hence your configuration works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

To configure url authorization you need to change the line `http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()`

to

`http.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers("someurl").hasAuthority("ROLE_SOMEROLE")
.antMatchers("/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN").authenticated()`

However it seems that what you want is to have these dynamically change at runtime. I'm not sure if spring let's you do that. However, you could achieve a similar behavior by making some changes to the design of your roles structure.

You need to add a grouping layer to your permissions and make those groups your user roles (These will be assigned to users). Then, your granted authorities will be the permissions assigned to your role/grouping. This way you can dynamically change the permissions under those groups without having to make changes to the code.

Example of role permission Structure (Pseudo java code):

NOTE: Role and Group are interchangeable

```
@Entity
public class Permission {

    private String name;

    private String description;

    ... // getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class Role {

   private String name;

   @ManyToOne
   private List<Permission> permissions;
   ... // getters and setters
}
```

First you need to have an url that does something. Let's say it creates a new employee record. So you need to create a new "createEmployee" permission and make that the authority needed to access that url. The idea here is to create permissions that is specific to the action that it's protecting. This way you won't have to change the permission in the future.

`http.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers("some-url").hasAuthority("createEmployee")
.antMatchers("/**").hasAuthority("admin").authenticated()`

Now all you need to do is to assign the "createEmployee" permission to a role which its duties include this action. Let's say for example it would be "hiringManager" role/grouping.

Ex of permission getting assigned to Role/Grouping:

```
Role hiringManager = new Role("hiringManager");
Permission createPermission = permissionRepository.findByName("createPermission");
hiringManager.getPermissions().add(createPermission);
```

This is just for illustration purposes. Ideally you would have a screen in your application that let's you create Groups and Permissions at run-time. Then you can assign or remove permissions from the groups as you see fit.

Note that this is just one solution for the technical side of things. That being said, even if it doesn't match your needs it should guide you to come up with whatever your business needs are.

Hope this helps!